# Possible to map over another map result, rxjs?

Tags: dictionary, rxjs, pipe, observable, angular7

I'm getting on angular 7 and having some issues understanding the way pipe syntax is working.

Here is my code so far :

```
    tests: Row[]
    public getTest() : Observable<Row[]> {
      return this.http.get<Test[]>(this.testUrl)
      .pipe(
        map((tests) => {
          tests.map(test => test.rows = this.tests)
          return this.tests;
    }))
  }
```

Here is my model :

```
export interface Test {
  total_rows: number;
  offset: number;
  rows: Row[];
}

export interface Row {
  id: string;
  key: Key;
  value?: any;
}

export interface Key {
  name: string;
}
```

Here is the JSON :

```
{
  "total_rows": 2,
  "offset": 0,
  "rows": [
    {
      "id": "54229d6897e1d1c7d603428a850081d5",
      "key": {
        "name": "test1"
      },
      "value": null
    },
    {
      "id": "54229d6897e1d1c7d603428a85010e03",
      "key": {
        "name": "test2"
      },
      "value": null
    }
  ]
}
```

And the data I would like to get is : an array of Rows

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, one method belongs to the [`Observal.map()`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) and the other one is original native [Javascript's array `.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Not sure what you are trying to achieve, if you just want to retrieve the array of `Rows` and assign it to `this.tests`, you can simply tranform the `Observable` using `Observable.map()` and there is no need to use JS array `.map()`. Remember to subscribe to your observable:

```
public getTest() : Observable<Row[]> {
  return this.http.get<Test[]>(this.testUrl)
  .pipe(
    map((tests) =>  tests.rows)))

//remember to subscribe
this.getTest().subscribe(results => this.tests = results) //assign the rows to local this.tests
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was getting mixed with map().